# Compute a feasible schedule for scheduling on identical parallel machines?

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete, scheduling, parallel

I am considering the offline version of identical parallel machine scheduling with arrival time and deadlines while allowing preemption and no assumption regarding the agreeability of the arrival and deadline.

So given $n$ jobs, where each job $i$ have an arrival time $a_i:a_i\geq0$, length $l_i: l_i>1$, and deadline $d_i: d_i>=a_i+l_i$.

How can I implement a feasible schedule such that $c_i <= d_i, \forall i$?

I understand that minimizing makespan or tardiness makes the problem NP-hard, even with preemption. However, I am not interested in minimizing makespan or any other objective. My objective is to find a feasible schedule if it exists.

The closest paper that proposes a feasible algorithm is Algorithm 1 in this paper [image: paper].

However, they assume that jobs must have a common deadline or submission time, which is not my case.